# AJAX How to submit different form data to external API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I wonder how can i submit multiple form data to external api. I have multiple different form with different data field.

But i will insert two of my form code here.

I have first form like below :

```html
<!-- Customer details form start here -->
                            <form id="maklumat_form" method="post">
                             <font color="#e4aa45">Maklumat Anda</font>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nama">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="No. Telefon">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                                        <select name="negeri" id="negeri">
                                        <option disabled selected>Negeri</option>
                                         <option></option>
                                        </select>
                                        <select name="bandar" id="bandar">
                                        <option disabled selected>Bandar</option>
                                         <option></option>
                                        </select>
                                        <input type="text" name="poskod" placeholder="Poskod">
                                    </div>
                                  
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                                        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Alamat" rows="5"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                  
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-12 columns">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Emel">
                                    </div>      
                            </div> 

                            <div class="row">           
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-5 columns">
                                        <button type="submit" class="submit">TEMPAH SEKARANG</button>
                                    </div>              
                            </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- end of order form -->
                    </form>
```

and 2nd form like below :

```html
<form id="sidebar_tempah_button">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="big-12 medium-12 columns">
                                <font color="#e4aa45">Pengangkutan</font>
                                <input style="width:50%;color:#e4aa45;" type="text" name="pengangkutan" class="span2" id="pengangkutan" disabled="disabled" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="big-12 medium-12 columns">
                             <div class="hidden2" id="tarikh_slot">
                                Tarikh & Slot
                                <input style="width:50%;" type="text" name="hari" class="submit" id="hari" readonly="true" value="KHAMIS">
                                <input style="width:50%;background-color:#2ecc71;color:white;" type="text" name="tarikh" class="bayar" id="tarikh" readonly="true" value="1-1-2017">
                                <input style="width:50%;background-color:#2ecc71;color:white;" type="text" name="slot" class="span2" id="slot" readonly="true" value="">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="big-12 medium-12 columns">
                                Jumlah Semua
                                <input style="width:50%;background-color:#e4aa45;color:black;" type="text" name="jumlah_semua" class="span2" id="jumlah_semua" disabled="disabled" value="">
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="big-12 medium-6 columns">                          
                            <button id="sidebar_tempah" type="submit" class="submit">TEMPAH SEKARANG</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

I want to send this form data to external api (BillPlz api). How can i do that ? there have tutorial for one form submission but not for multiple form submission.

The api doc state this :

"With shell, you can just pass the correct HTTP Basic Auth credential with each request.
curl https://www.billplz.com/api/v2/bills \
  -u 73eb57f0-7d4e-42b9-a544-aeac6e4b0f81: \
  -d collection_id=inbmmepb \ "

I dont really understand how to send this kind of data using ajax. Sorry im new with this.

Comment: access all the forms in the page like `document.getElementsByTagName('form')` and extract the required values and submit them.

Comment: Sorry, i not really understand what you saying. I kinda new with this ajax. @AshutoshTripathi

Comment: You need to break this question in at least 2 separate ones: "how to submit multiple forms with javascript" and "how to send cURL request" with whatever programming language you use (second one you need because you are dealing with bills here and some info that you'll be sending needs to be hidden). I would just recommend reading a tutorial on cURL, [here is one for php](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/techniques-for-mastering-curl--net-8470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit whatever data you want regardless of number of forms using Ajax. Below Ajax does the same

```
var  formData = "name=ravi&age=31";  //Name value Pair
or
var formData = {name:"ravi",age:"31"}; //Array 

$.ajax({
url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
type: "POST",
data : formData,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    //data - response from server
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{

}
});
```

You can edit above line `var formData = {name:"ravi",age:"31"}; //Array` with whatever data you want to send to API regardless of number of forms.
Only thing you have to make note on is on submit of which form you have to call API.

Update:

`var formData = {name:"ravi",age:"31"}; //Array` is the data that you want to send to API

`url : "AJAX_POST_URL"` is the URL of your API.

`data : formData,`  send your form data to API.

If you want to learn refer the link [Link](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! but, i not really understand what they state in the api doc something like below i dont understand how to post the data.

curl https://www.billplz.com/api/v2/bills \
  -u 73eb57f0-7d4e-42b9-a544-aeac6e4b0f81: \
  -d collection_id=inbmmepb \

Comment: Updated my answer explaining about Ajax. If you are new, follow the link shared. Learn how to consume API using Ajax ?.